# In javascript, when doing getElementById().onclick = function, why are the function () not necessary?

Tags: javascript

Sorry it's hard to come up with a title for that. I'm still new to javascript and something is confusing me.

Here's my code

```
function getRandom() {
  document.getElementById('divtest').innerHTML = (Math.floor(Math.random()* 20))
}

document.getElementById('buttontest').onclick = getRandom
```

So, usually, when calling a function somewhere in the document, or even when adding the onclick='myFunction()' right in the html, I need to write myFunction(), with the paranthese.

But here, when I do the .onclick on the getElementById, my code does not work if I write = getRandom(), it needs to be = getRandom, as shown in my code snippet.

Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: You are passing a reference to the function. If you would write getRandom(), you would pass whatever gets returned from the function, as you are calling the function before the onclick happens

Comment: https://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2

Comment: you need to understand difference between **function call** and **function reference**, `myFunction()` will execute the function and `myFunction` will give the referance

Comment: "*usually, when calling a function somewhere*" - yes, when calling it. But we don't want to do that here. We want the click handler to get called by the DOM when the user clicks the element.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard of the distinction between function call and function reference. I'll go and read up on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `()` you make a call of a function. In your case if you add `()` then you call `getRandom`, the result, which is `undefined`, will be assigned to the `onclick` event handler. So you want to assign the function itself. Consider example:

```
var func = function () { return 2 }
console.log(func) //=> ƒ () { return 2 }
console.log(func()) //=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you're passing a reference to the function, not calling it (which would add the return value of the function as callback).

Whereas when defining a callback function in HTML you are writing the complete invocation into the HTML element attribute.

Comment: There are no pointers in JS. Please call it "reference", or "function object".

Comment: An example of what you mean could be helpful here too.  Understanding function references can be difficult for those just learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` is sort of "pointing" to the function which contains the code that is to be run when a click event is encountered on that element. It is not a normal "call" to the function where you would get some value as return. There you would use the parentheses. Here, however you are setting the function as the handler for the click event.